# Promises Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've looked through several promise syntax, but I'm really not understanding it (including the ones that had examples).  Most of them resolved a variable, but mine is a bit more complex, and I can't seem to get it running right.

I'm using Firebase to get the current user, and want it to run the next lines AFTER I get the user.

Here's my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        var user = fire.auth().currentUser};
        resolve(
            if(user) {
                console.log('Favorites: requesting favorites');
                fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                var recipes_obj = snapshot.val();
                let recipes = [];
                for (let id in recipes_obj) {
                    let recipe = recipes_obj[id];
                    recipe.id = id;
                    recipes.push(recipe);
                    console.log("recipes: ", recipes)
            }
                console.log("recipes outside", recipes);
                this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                console.log('Favorites: no user')
            }
        )
}
```

I've also tried it like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    var user = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(fire.auth().currentUser).then(() => {
            if(user) {
                console.log('Favorites: requesting favorites');
                fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                    var recipes_obj = snapshot.val();
                    let recipes = [];
                    for (let id in recipes_obj) {
                        let recipe = recipes_obj[id];
                        recipe.id = id;
                        recipes.push(recipe);
                        console.log("recipes: ", recipes)
                    }
                    console.log("recipes outside", recipes);
                    this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                console.log('Favorites: no user')
            }
        })

    })
```

Comment: `someFunctionName(if(user) {` - does that look like javascript syntax? so it wont work with `resolve` either - in fact neither of those blocks are even valid syntax, so fixing your logic will be difficult until you fix your syntax

Comment: as far as promise syntax goes - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var user = fire.auth().currentUser
```

This code is not asynchronous.  When this line executes, you have the user immediately in `var user`.  You don't need to use a promise to do something in response to getting the user - you already have it.

The only time you need to create a new Promise object and resolve it is when you have some work that run asynchronously and you have no other promise to indicate when that work is complete.

In your code you also don't return your new promise to the caller.  This means the promise is useless.  Unless you hand a promise off to another bit of code that operates in response to its resolution, it doesn't really help the situation.  In other words, your promise is not doing anything here.

The only bit of code that's asynchronous in your code is the fetch from the database:

```
fire.database().ref('/favourites/' + user.uid).once('value')
```

`once()` returns a promise.  In your code, you're calling the then() method on that promise to do more work after the result is available.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem with another Firebase command, but when I was using this, the reason why I tried to use Promises was because when I ran the program with the console.logs, it showed that the user was undefined.  And it wasn't until the program ran again the second time that the user was defined.  So I assumed that the program went through, tried to get the user, but while it got the user, it went through the if statement, failed since there was no user yet, and went straight to the else statement (I was getting the console.log from the else).

Comment: There will be no user if they are not logged in.  You should always check this case before using currentUser if your code could run when there is no one authenticated.  You can also use an auth listener to find out exactly when someone logs in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your not actually calling your promise anywhere just declaring it inside your componentDidMount? Try something like this..  BTW, never used firebase so not sure on the below api use.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        var promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
             let user = ()=> fire.auth().currentUser
             resolve(user)
           })

        promise().then((user)=>{
                        if(user) {
                   return fire.database().ref(`/favourites/${user.uid}`).once('value')
                }
                    })
                    .then((snapshot)=>{
                        //Do other stuff with snapshot
                })
        }
```